# Asymptotic of $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n^{1-a} \rfloor} \frac{(n^{2(1-a)})^k}{(k!)^2}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Let $a \in (0,1)$, what is the asymptotic behaviour of $\displaystyle{S_n := \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n^{1-a} \rfloor} \frac{(n^{2(1-a)})^k}{(k!)^2}}$ ?

More precisely, is it possible to have an asymptotic equivalence, or at least an upper-bound/lower-bound ?

Comment: what does $S_n$ count ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM It looks weird at first sight but if you prefer : i'm interested in $\displaystyle{S_n := \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \lambda_n \rfloor} \frac{(\lambda_n^2)^k}{(k!)^2}}$ with $\lambda_n \to \infty$. I know that $\displaystyle{\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(\lambda_n^2)^k}{(k!)^2}=I_0(\lambda_n)}$ but taking the limit $n\to\infty$ isn't the same as $\lim_n S_n$.  If there is a general way to study this kind of thing, let me know !